# An access violation (segmentation fault) raised in my program?

Tags: c++, if-statement, crash, while-loop, counter

This program has been a huge headache for me. For whatever reason it crashes as soon as it reaches "student 3". I can't find any infinite loops that it is getting stuck in or any other reason for it to crash at that point. Any help much be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
 const int ARRAY_SIZE_TWO = 4;
 const int ARRAY_SIZE_THREE = 20;
 string names[ARRAY_SIZE];
 double grades[ARRAY_SIZE];
 double average[ARRAY_SIZE];
 double averageFinal[ARRAY_SIZE];
 string letter[ARRAY_SIZE] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "F"};
 string studentLetter[ARRAY_SIZE]; 
 int counterOne = 0;
 int counterTwo = 0;
 int counterThree = 0;
 double temp;
 while (counterOne < ARRAY_SIZE)
 {
  system("CLS");
  cout<<"Enter the name of student number " <<(counterOne + 1) <<":"<<endl;
  cin>>names[counterOne];
  while(counterTwo < ARRAY_SIZE_TWO)
  {
   system("CLS");
   cout<<"Enter the test scores for " <<names[counterOne] <<":" <<endl;
   cout<<"Enter test score number " <<(counterTwo + 1) <<" for " <<names[counterOne] <<":" <<endl;
   cin>>grades[counterThree];
   counterTwo += 1;
   counterThree += 1;
   average[counterOne] += grades[counterThree];
  }
  counterTwo = 0;
  counterOne += 1;
 }
 counterOne = 0;
 counterTwo = 0;
 counterThree = 0;
 while(counterOne < ARRAY_SIZE)
 {
  averageFinal[counterOne] = average[counterOne] / 12;
  if (averageFinal[counterOne] < 89)
  {
   studentLetter[counterOne] = letter[0];
  }
  else if (averageFinal[counterOne] < 79)
  {
   studentLetter[counterOne] = letter[1];
  }
  else if (averageFinal[counterOne] < 69)
  {
   studentLetter[counterOne] = letter[2];
  }
  else if (averageFinal[counterOne] < 59)
  {
   studentLetter[counterOne] = letter[3];
  }
  else
  {
   studentLetter[counterOne] = letter[4];
  }
  counterOne += 1;
 }

 while(counterTwo < ARRAY_SIZE)
 {
  cout<<names[counterTwo] <<":" <<endl <<"Average: " <<averageFinal <<"%" <<endl <<"Letter Grade: " <<studentLetter[counterTwo] <<endl;
  counterTwo += 1;
 }
 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you trace it to the line of code that is causing the problem? That would help us help you.

Comment: Irrelevant but the first if statement is always true for numbers < 89... that is you need a range check...  but check that you are not going out of bounds?

Comment: honestly I'm not sure how to trace line of code that is causing the issue. I'm still new to C++. Is there any way I could run the program line by line?

Comment: Why aren't you reseting `CounterThree`?

Comment: counterThree is being used to calculate the average later on, I can't test how I'm going to do the average calculation until I get past the input stage.

Comment: Is there any way I could run the program line by line? Yes use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As vidit points out, counterThree is allowed to overflow ARRAY_SIZE in the read loop.  You need to reset it, or use a different counter later on.  A good practice is also to keep the scope of variables as narrow as possible, and not to re-use variables (avoid "temps"), which can lead to confusion in bookkeeping.